# How can I determine if a point is hidden on a 3D Scatterplot (Plotly.js)?

Tags: d3.js, svg, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly.js to draw a 3-D scatter plot . On zoom , I want to check which points are visible . Can this be done on svg level ? or any plotly expert ?

Snippet:

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var trace = {
  x: [1, 7, 2, 4,1],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12,2],
  z: [1, 2, 4, 8,4],

  //  x: [1,2],
  //y: [12,15],
  //z: [1, 4],
mode: 'markers' ,
type: 'scatter3d' ,
marker: {size:5 }
}


var data = [trace];
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 0,
    r: 0,
    b: 0,
    t: 0} ,
  //title: {text: 'ReOptim8 Scatter Plot'},
  scene: {
    yaxis:{title: 'X-axis'},
    xaxis:{title: 'y-axis'},
    zaxis:{title: 'z-axis'},
        camera: {eye: {x:1.25, y:1.25, z:1.25}}
        }
};

var config = {
  displayModebar : true,
  displaylogo: false,
  responsive: true
  };

Plotly.plot( myPlot, data, layout, config );
```

Code pen link below :

https://codepen.io/aniwar/pen/wLOzZv